# Javascript : Load a page (from a list of pages) into a div, and display its URL in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the background: I've got a Javascript function I wrote that uses a search field to search a list of relevant links, and based on the users preferences either display that link they searched for in a div on the same page OR in a new window using _blank.

I soon realized my problem is that I want users to be able to still see the full page URL if they opted to load the page inside a div instead of in a new tab. I want them to still be able to copy/paste the URL. I figured since I've already got the Javascript function creating the link in full, I would simply add a 'document.getElementByID('IDHERE').value = processedPage;, but that (for whatever reason) doesn't seem to be working?

Below is my Javascript for reference:

```
    /* Function to go jump to a user guide */
function goTo() {
    var searchAgainst = document.getElementById('guidesSearch').value; // get the search value
    nWT_check = localStorage.getItem('newWindowToggle');
    var processedPage = 'http://update.my-site.com/onlinehelp/';
    var findFlag = 0;

    for (i=0; i<allGuides.length; i++) {
        if (searchAgainst == allGuides[i]) {
            findFlag = 1;
            processedPage += allURLs[i];
            if (nWT_check == '0') {  //Check against the site options
                alert(processedPage); // ALERT to see if processedPage is correct. It is, and this alert triggers.
                document.getElementById('guidesLink').value = processedPage; // This does not seem to trigger?
                document.getElementById('guidesFrame').src = processedPage; // But then this does, which loads the new page in the DIV.
            }
            else if (nWT_check == '1') {
                window.open(processedPage,'_blank');
            }
        }
    }
    if (findFlag == 0) {
        $('#notFoundModal').modal();
    }
}
```

So basically, it looks at the localStorage item, and if it is 0, it does DIV, if it is 1, it does new page. I'm trying to debug the if (nWT_check == '0') {  //Check against the site options part.

I know every ones time and knowledge is valuable and people don't have time to debug complex codes all the time but any insight into what I might be doing wrong or how to better approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a URL hash technique.

If your main page is `index.php`, as each page is loaded by Ajax, you change the document location hash (`document.location.hash='...'`) to a new value using JavaScript:

```
index.php#pageName
```

So when the main page loads, use JavaScript to see if it has a hash value, then using the hash value, go grab the matching content using AJAX.

This article explains the details of how this works: http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2011/10/must-know-url-hashtechniques-for-ajax-applications/

The beauty of this technique is that the user can both bookmark and share the URL and it will still work.

Comment: I'm already using a hashing technique to load the main pages I think, because my main is index.php#home and the different pages across the top load in as #help, #guides, etc. My scenario I *THINK* might be different, because what I'm trying to do is keep them on the #guides hash, but inside that guides page load ANOTHER page (the guide itself) into a div, then display its URL. Does that change things? Or make any sense at all? (lol). I'm just not sure if I can double up on the hash technique for this, but I'm going to look at your article anyway and the reply is much appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth adding that the guides in question that I am trying to load and link to are on a separate server, so they aren't local resources within the website itself. Therefore I'm loading in the full URL address.

Comment: You could modify your hash handler to use delimiters and multiple pages and make chained calls. I've done this before with good success. "#guides_sec1_page3". Just run your calls sequentially.

Comment: an elegant solution. it seemed like a solid idea but then I realized that it wouldn't work out in this case, but in general practice is what I will be doing from now on. The reason this won't work is because the address in the URL bar cannot be given out, as it's an internal link (requires SharePoint access), so if I used hash and those URLs then clients can't reach the page because they need a domain password. I'm trying to use the clientside links, which are accessible to guests. This way they can see the address in the input field and copy/paste it. I appreciate your time tho!

Comment: hahaha trust me I'd avoid it if I could but I stepped in on the mid to tail end of an existing project that has a lot of internal SharePoint references and some client side references so it's a bit of a puzzle.. I was just hoping for a quick "oh hey idiot you missed a dot here", but I knew it couldn't be that simple :p

Answer (score 0):

I would try using jQuery to set the value of the field instead:

```
$("#guidesLink").val(processedPage);
```

This might fix some potential browser quirks with setting an input field value.